# Is it possible to see a smart contract code hash from within a smart contract?

Tags: smart-contract

I would like to check the code hash of an account from within my smart contract. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since learned that this isn't possible, and could only be done using an external oracle or other off-chain service. If this changes in the future I will update this answer.

Comment: I wrote the patch for this feature, but not yet merged. https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/pull/7835

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no WASM intrinsic to do that. However, Newdex keeps a list of all smart contracts for anyone to check on-chain. [See here for more details](https://cmichel.io/how-to-check-if-an-eos-account-has-a-smart-contract/)

Answer (score -1):

**Update** Actually, you don't have access to `account_object` from the contract.

You can use `account.code_version`.

See https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/0f6695cb8d31e3d2f318d1720e9d9ad23e1ce80d/libraries/chain/eosio_contract.cpp#L151

From cleos do: `cleos get code <accountName>`

Comment: The question asks how to do it from within a smart contract, not how to do it with cleos.